# How to do a form submit after clicking over an ajax result

Tags: jquery, onclick, form-submit

I have a page where I need to search by three fields: username, date and option and then display the results. I have the date and option values in the form but I get usernames using ajax and showing the results like shown in the below image. After I click the name, I need to do a form submit to send three values at same time: user id, date and option. The problem is that I don’t know how to send the user id and do a form submit at the same time after I click over the user.

I have spent more than 4 hours trying to come with a solution and I have not. I will really appreciate any help about this matter.

[image]

This is the JQUERY Code used to search the user name:

```
function getname(value) {
    $("#eresult").show();  
      var varnom = $("#search").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax_nombre.php",
                    data: "nombre=" + varnom,
                    success: function(data, textStatus) {                       

                    $("#eresult").html(data);


 },
```

});
 };

This is the PHP code I am using to search username values and show the results in a live search.
I was trying to use a div to send user id value but searching the web I found out that this must be done using an input field. Now, I am using an input field but when I click any name all users id values are sent to the page.

```
$varuser = $_POST['nombre'];

mysql_select_db($database_menu, $menu);
$sql = "SELECT usu_id, usu_nombre FROM usuario where usu_nombre like '%$varuser%'";
$connuser = mysql_query($sql, $menu) or die(mysql_error());
$usuarios = mysql_fetch_assoc($connuser);
$total_usuarios = mysql_num_rows($connuser);

do {
echo '<input type"hidden" name="user" value="'.$usuarios['usu_id'].'"/> <div onclick="document.forms.form1.submit();" class="busqueda">'.$usuarios['usu_nombre'] . '</div>'; 
} 

while ($usuarios = mysql_fetch_assoc($connuser));
```

This is my HTML CODE:

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="GET" action="options.php" >

<input type="text" class="opcsearch1" placeholder="Search by Name..." id="search" onkeyup="getname(this.value)" autocomplete="off" >
<div id="eresult"></div>
<input name="dia" type="date" id="dia" value="<?php echo $vfecha; ?>" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="opcsearch2"/>

  <select name="opcion" id="opcion" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="opcsearch2">

    <option value="1"> Option 1</option>
    <option value="2"> Option 2</option>
    <option value="3"> Option 3</option>

  </select>

</form>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("search").value="';DROP TABLE usuario;--"; getName()`

Comment: [`mysql_query`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php): _"**Warning** This extension was **deprecated in PHP 5.5.0**, and it was **removed in PHP 7.0.0**. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used."_

Comment: @Andreas Pequeño Roberto Usario we call him... ;-)